# If statement only checks variable value once in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

I am trying to understand how javascript (jquery in this case) if statements work. I thought i understood but i don't fully get some things. Please see the code below. Why is it when i click on the element with the class of "cat" that it does not remove the class of "black" and add the class of "red".

```
$(function() {

 var cat = true;

$( ".cat" ).click(function() {
  cat = false;
});

if (cat === true) {
  $('.cat').removeClass('red').addClass('black');
} else {
  $('.cat').removeClass('black').addClass('red');

}
});
```

i know there is probably a very simple answer to this but i'm just learning so any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't put the `if` statement inside the `click` function, so it won't execute.

Comment: Fist you set `cat` to true, then you immediately check if it is identical to true and since it is, you remove the red class and add the black. The only thing that happens when someone click on the cat-element, is that you set the variable `cat` to false and nothing more.

Comment: It is not the if-statement that is the problem, but when the code is executed. First you set cat to true, then you add a click-handler, and then you check if cat is true (and it will always be true). Sometime in the future the cat-element might be clicked, but the only thing that you do then is to set the cat-variable to false, because that is the only thing you have put in your click-event-handler. Your if-statement will not be reevaluated, because it is not part of your click-event-handler.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

Toggle the value of cat and put the if block inside the function that you want to bind with the event 'click':

```
$(".cat").click(function() {
  cat = !cat;
  if (cat === true) {
    $('.cat').removeClass('red').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('.cat').removeClass('black').addClass('red');
  }
});
```

Edit: Simpler way to do this is to use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
 $(".cat").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('red black');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check on click, put the if inside the click event. The reason why your solution doesn't work is because you attach a listener to the element, but you immediately do a check. The check doesn't happen every time the user clicks, just once. You must put it in the listener's callback function so it executes every time the element is clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $(".cat").click(function() {
        $(".cat").toggleClass("black red");
    });
});
```

How this works is it attaches a click event to `.cat` and, on click, toggles the classes `black` and `red`. This completely gets rid of the checking because that isn't necessary. Just toggle the classes on click. Also, no need to repeat the selector, just use `this`. Here's a snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".cat").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("black red");
    });
});
```

```css
.black {
  color: black;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat red">Test</div>
```

Comment: This is a better solution, but it doesn't really explain why the OP's code doesn't work...

Comment: @nnnnnn Updated! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not removing class `black` and adding class `red` because your `if(){}else{}` code block running when your page is loading. When you are clicking the `cat` class it is only assigning the value of cat variable to `false`. since your `if else` code block is out of your click function that is why it is not executing again. and that is why it is not working. To work your code place your if else code block in the click function like this:

```
$( ".cat" ).click(function() {
          cat = false;
          if (cat === true) {
            $('.cat').removeClass('red').addClass('black');
            } else {
              $('.cat').removeClass('black').addClass('red');

            };
        });
```

Comment: You missed the thing that was asked: why it doesn't change when the .cat-element is clicked.... And that is because the if-statement has been run at initialization time, and is never run when the element is clicked.